# Unable to access advanced reporting

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, advanced-reporting

We used to be able to access advanced reporting now we are displayed with the following

```
Your Base URL has been changed and your reports are being updated. Advanced Reporting will be available once this change has been processed. Please try again later.
```

Our site meets all the criteria of being on SSL, on a public server etc. Any assistance in getting this working again would be great. Also to note under config settings advanced reporting the status never moves from pending.

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements :**

1. The website must run on a public web server.
2. The domain must have a valid security (SSL) certificate.
3. Magento must have been installed or upgraded successfully without error.
4. In the Magento configuration, the Base URL (Secure) setting for the store view must point to the secure URL. For example **https://yourdomain.com**
5. In the Magento configuration, Use Secure URLs on Storefront, and Use Secure URLs in Admin must be set to **“Yes.**”
6. Make sure that **Magento crontab** is created and cron jobs are running on the installed server.

**Troubleshooting :**

> If you get a 404 “Page Not Found” message, verify that your store meets the requirements for Advanced Reporting. Then, follow the instructions to verify that the integration is installed.

`Verify that the Integration is Active`

On the Admin menu, choose `System > Extensions >  Integration`

Verify that the Magento Analytics user integration appears in the list, and that the Status is **“Active.”**

To reestablish the user, click Reauthorize. [Then, do the following](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html)

---

**Update :**

This error comes from the below path.

> vendor/magento/module-analytics/Model/ReportUrlProvider.php

Find function `public function getUrl()` and debug.

In my case, I got a solution after debugging this function.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Done all that no result

Comment: Have you follow the Troubleshooting?

Comment: Yes. I have completed all the above. It was working 2 weeks ago now it isn’t. I suspect it’s just dodge Magento code or the adobe google shopping that I’ve installed as broken it

Comment: See my answer updates.

Comment: If my answer is useful to you then accept an answer and Up vote, so it will be useful to another user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make Magento BI work that is many factors, most of the time it's not just having it installed. Open the HTTP answer from your browser you will notice that the 404 page isn't a 404, it's a 401, which means **unauthorized**.

#### Step 1 - Basic configuration

Make sure to whitelist these Magento BI IPs on your CDN and WAF.

Advance Reporting End point: https://advancedreporting.rjmetrics.com/

IPs:

```
34.206.147.74

35.172.154.189

54.144.21.42

3.85.182.28

52.73.51.61
```

#### Step 2 - Check cronjobs

Make sure your cronjobs are running, maybe they are configured but not running. You can download [Magerun 2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) and run this command below regularly to ensure you don't miss hundreds of cronjobs.

```
./var/n98-magerun2.phar db:query "SELECT count(*) 'total' from cron_schedule WHERE status='missed' OR status='error' AND created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE);" | grep -v total
```

If you have hundreds of missed cronjobs, you will need to fix them first.

#### Step 3 - Prepare report folder

Then make sure the folder permissions are ok, and create a folder that would be automatically created, but we want to avoid possible gaps here.
Don't use sudo, in case you run it on Platform.sh and Magento Cloud.

```
mkdir pub/media/analytics
sudo find . -typef -execchmod664 {} \;
sudo find . -typed -execchmod775 {} \;
sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -typef -execchmodg+w {} \;
sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -typed -execchmodg+ws {} \;
sudo chmodu+x bin/magento
```

#### Step 4 - Reenable it

Go to your admin panel **Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Advanced Reporting** and disable, save, then enable, and save the config again.

[image: Magento BI Enable and Disable]

#### Step 5 - Reauthorize it

Then go to **System > Extensions > Integration** and **Reauthorize** it.

[image: Magento BI Reauthorize]

#### Step 6 - Token created

Then check if you have a token by using this query in your database.

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'analytics/general/token' \G
```

In case you don't have it, you need to figure out, why the last steps didn't create it.

#### Step 7 - Manually execution

The report cronjob runs each 24h, so I run Magerun 2 command to run the reports manually using the command below and selecting the following sequence.

```
./var/n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run
```

Sequence

1. **analytics_subscribe**
2. You can try to reauthorize at this stage if the first time without it doesn't work.
3. **analytics_update**
4. **analytics_collect_data**

#### Step 8 - Confirming report file

By running the command below you ensure that the report file is generated on your server side, and it's ready to be collected by Magento BI (each 24h from their side).

```
ls -ltr pub/media/analytics/
```

Running the command `bin/magento module:status` you can confirm if these essential modules are enabled.

```
Magento_AdminAnalytics

Magento_CatalogPageBuilderAnalytics

Magento_CatalogPageBuilderAnalyticsStaging

Magento_CmsPageBuilderAnalytics

Magento_CmsPageBuilderAnalyticsStaging

Magento_Analytics

Magento_GoogleAnalytics

Magento_CatalogAnalytics

Magento_PageBuilderAnalytics

Magento_QuoteAnalytics

Magento_ReviewAnalytics

Magento_BannerPageBuilderAnalytics

Magento_SalesAnalytics

Magento_CustomerAnalytics

Magento_PageBuilderAdminAnalytics

Magento_WishlistAnalytics
```

#### Step 9 - Possible extra errors

You might see logs from Magento BI, with 200 or 401.

```
zgrep  -i analytics /var/log/nginx/access.log* |  grep MagentoBI
```

Try this one too

```
zgrep analytics_collect_data var/log/support_report.log* | tail
```

On Plataform.sh or Magento Cloud, you can run:

```
zgrep  -i analytics /var/log/platform/xcykllamfhefo/access.log* |  grep MagentoBI
```

You might see a log like this example:

```
184.31.1.70 - - [28/Apr/2023:10:45:14 +0000] "GET /rest/V1/analytics/link HTTP/1.1" 200 190 "-" "MagentoBI"
23.195.73.31 - - [28/Apr/2023:13:43:29 +0000] "GET /rest/V1/analytics/link HTTP/1.1" 401 133 "-" "MagentoBI"
```

As you can see, my access log reported 401 because my WAF (Firewall) was blocking the external system connection.

#### Step 10 - Wait for the data

You might see an empty dashboard, like the image below. It takes 24h to recognize the data you've sent from Magento to Advanced Reporting.

[image: Magento Advanced Reporting Dashboard]